# How to get latest video streamed to client without using cached copy?

Tags: c#, iis-7, servicestack

We stream videos to our client and we noticed an issue where a video was uploaded but the browser still played the cached value (old video).

I assume this is related to the etag of the video (as I can see in fiddler).

So my question is, if I upload a new version of a video and the client then makes a request for the video, how can I ensure that the latest upload video is returned and not the cached copy from the client browser?

Answer (score 2):

How are you "streaming" your videos?

If just a download link then perhaps look at [Cache busting in ASP.NET](http://madskristensen.net/post/Cache-busting-in-ASPNET.aspx), works fine with ServiceStack for static content, though not tried it with video. If your returning a stream, perhaps `[AddHeader(CacheControl = "private")]`?

Or specify static cache settings in AppHost Configure method:

```
this.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
                    AddMaxAgeForStaticMimeTypes =
                        new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>
                            {
                                {
                                    "image/jpeg", 
                                    TimeSpan.FromDays(7.0)
                                },
                                {
                                    "video/mpeg", 
                                    TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)
                                }, 
                            } });
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin for reply. We have ts and mp4 videos. The mp4 videos are accessed directory with a url where as the ts videos use a http handler (unfortunately it was not written in servicestack). I initially though it was an etag issue but I am not seeing any 304 responses so it must be cache settings as you mentioned above. I'll give that a try.